# Parse boolean attributes with DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to parse a simple config file with minimized Boolean attributes and the DOMDocument is not having it.  I am trying to load the following:

```
<config>
    <text id='name' required>
        <label>Name:</label>
    </text>
</config>
```

with the following code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=FALSE;
if($dom->LoadXML($template) === FALSE){
    throw new Exception("Could not parse template");
}
```

I am getting a warning that

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Specification mandate value for attribute required in Entity, line: 2
```

Am I missing a flag or something to get DOMDocument to parse the minimum boolean attribute?

Comment: Try to set a value in your XML for <text id='name' required> (e.g. <text id='name' required='true'> or <text id='name' required='required'>).

Comment: That does seem to solve the problem, but I can't change the config files.  I am getting the same config as other tools and have to replicate their behavior for this new system.

Comment: Can you map the problematic attributes from the XML before using them in the DomDocument to replace them to an acceptable value? It's not a beautiful solution, but if you just load the config file and it's not with the proper information, I think you should consider the need to re-write it.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the person who originally implemented this in perl wrote their own parser.  I can probably clean it with some regex, but it means parsing the config at least twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute without a value is not valid syntax in either [XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) or [1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-starttags), so what you have isn't XML. You should get that fixed.

Pretending that's not possible, you *can* use:

```
$dom->loadHTML($template, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
```

instead, which uses a parsing mode that's much more forgiving, but you'll get warnings about invalid HTML tags. So you'll also need [`libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) and [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) (which you should probably be using anyway to deal with errors) and ignore anything with an error code of [801](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#XML_HTML_UNKNOWN_TAG).

#### Example:

```
$notxml = <<<'XML'
<config>
    <text id='name' required>
        <label>Name:</label>
    </text>
</config>
XML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($notxml, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    // Ignore unknown tag errors
    if ($error->code === 801) continue;

    throw new Exception("Could not parse template");
}
libxml_clear_errors();

// do your stuff if everything didn't go completely awry

echo $dom->saveHTML(); // Just to prove it worked
```

#### Outputs:

```
<config>
    <text id="name" required>
        <label>Name:</label>
    </text>
</config>
```